# Python use of shell function

Tags: python, bash, shell, environment-variables

I am using Msys2 portable under Win 10, but I guess this applies equally well for many other Linuxes/bashes.

**How can I have a python script, when run from the shell prompt, know about its shell functions and corresponding parameters?**

I have a bash shell where I have defined a shell function `myfun`

```
$ type myfun
myfun is a function
myfun ()
{
    ...
    (this contains a call to a shell script, 
      that is found in a directory which is part of $PATH)
}
```

that may take parameters, e.g., `$ myfun d`,
and I have a python script `myscript.py` which works well when run from the bash shell.
Now I want to add lines to `myscript.py` to execute `myfun` from within it, and have it working also with (same as before)

```
$ python3 myscript.py
```

---

---

**EDIT #1**:
After the answer received, I exported the function with `export -f myfun`.
Then I tried 6 alternatives in my script: (Using/Not using `bash -c`), combined with (`subprocess.run`, `os.system`, `os.popen`).

I am listing here, for each of the 6 combinations, the lines added to `myscript.py`, and the output obtained when executing `python3 myscript.py`:

1. Added

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["myfun", "d"])
```

Obtained (same as before)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'myfun'
```

2. Added

```
import os
os.system("myfun d")
```

Obtained the expected result.

3. Added

```
import os
stream = os.popen("myfun d")
```

Obtained
No errors, but apparently doing nothing (very strange, have to check further what happens).

4. Added

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["bash", "-c", "myfun", "d"])
```

Obtained:
Executed the function, but ignoring the function argument.

5. Added

```
import os
os.system("bash -c \"myfun d\"")
```

Obtained the expected result.

6. Added

```
import os
stream = os.popen("bash -c \"myfun d\"")
```

Obtained
No errors, but apparently doing nothing (very strange, have to check further what happens).

---

---

**Orginial question and status**:

I tried a few options, all failed (see details below). 
On one hand, it seems that, even executing `myscript.py` from the bash shell, it launches a separate `sh` shell without knowledge of my shell functions.
On the other hand, if adding `print( os.environ )` to `myscript.py`, I see environment variables that are set in `~/.bashrc`, so at least that is correctly inherited by the script from the shell.

---

I am listing here the lines added to `myscript.py`, and the output obtained when executing `python3 myscript.py`:

1. Added

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["myfun", "d"])
```

Obtained

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'myfun'
```

2. Added

```
import os
os.system("myfun d")
```

Obtained

```
sh: myfun: command not found
```

3. Added

```
import os
stream = os.popen("myfun d")
```

Obtained

```
/bin/sh: myfun: command not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Environment by default is private. Export the function and make sure that `bash` is run in the system call. `myfun` is a **bash** function, you have to run `bash` to run it's function.

```
$ myfun() { echo 1; }
$ export -f myfun
$ python <<<'import os; os.system("bash -c myfun")'
1
$ python <<<'import subprocess as s; s.run(["bash", "-c", "myfun"])'
1
$ python <<<'import os; os.popen("bash -c \'myfun"); # ... '
```

I usually pass arguments to internal bash commands as arguments to script and pass properly quoted `$@` expansion:

```
$ myfun() { echo "\$#=$#" "\$*=$*"; }
$ export -f myfun
$ python <<<'import os; os.system("bash -c \"myfun \\\"\$@\\\"\" -- d")'
$#=1 $*=d

# or way better use subprocess
$ python <<<'import subprocess as s; s.run(["bash", "-c", "myfun \"$@\"", "--", "d"])'
$#=1 $*=d

# but still can do the more unsafe version
# that will undergo word expansion or you have to properly escape the strings
# (and double-double escape for `os.systems`)
$ python <<<'import subprocess as s; s.run(["bash", "-c", "myfun d"])'
$#=1 $*=d
```

Comment: Exporting `myfun` was a necessary step I missed.
Fixing that, `bash -c` may not be needed (depending on what I use for executing `myfun` ).
And even when adding `bash -c`, for some ways of executing `myfun` I still couldn't make it work.
Note: `myfun` takes parameters, which makes things a little trickier.
I didn't clarify this before since I was one step behind this issue.
I updated this in edited OP.
Note: According to the results I obtained, I guess there might be a gap between the way you demonstrate how things work `$ python <<< ...` and the way I execute `myscript.py`.

Comment: `depending on what I use for executing the function` -> Most probably depending on what is stored as the default shell in /etc/passwd for the current user. `Note: the function I use takes parameters, which makes things a little trickier.` So it's a good opportunity to learn how to properly quote bash arguments. Tip: `printf "%q"` can be helpful in bash (there's I think something in python for quoting shell arguments).

Comment: `I guess there might be a gap between the way you demonstrate how things work` Well, the only difference is in intepreting the single quote character - it is ending the quoting. But after copying the commands without single quotes inside a script they work the same. Edited the answer with some samples that pass a single argument `d`.

Comment: All your three versions worked for me too (cannot upvote twice!!). I could not make `os.popen` work.

Comment: `python <<<'import os; p = os.popen("bash -c myfun"); line = p.readlines(); print(line)'` works fine for me. But `subprocess.Popen` is preferred over `os.popen[1,2,3]`, because quoting.

Comment: I have tried the above solutions for a function defined in my bashrc but it doesn't work. `subprocess.run(["export", '-f', "func", ";", 'func', "arg"], capture_output=True, shell=True, check=True, env=my_env)`

Comment: You have to export the function from where it's defined, not inside subprocess... Also make sure your bashrc is actually sourced.